# Which C++ IO interfaces for a complex data source i.e. converter

Tags: object-oriented, c++, c++11, io

### My question:

When you've got a complex converter like, that takes chunks or large result sets out of a database, converts it into a line by line file/resource in the end, should one either design it as `std::basic_streambuf` or should it be a `std::basic_istream` or something different, using C++?!

To better describe it look at the diagram below or use this text data flow:

```
A(ODB) -[maybe many rows]-> COSTLY CONVERSION  -[many text lines]->  ????  --> std::istream
                                                                     ????  --> std::ofstream
                                                                     ????  --> std::ostream
```

Note: The data volume may be large, from MB up to GB, so data could be converted in chunks and lazy from the database, which will lead to a chunk of text lines.
I my assumed approach at the moment for ???? was `std::basic_streambuf`

### My assumption:

AFAIK the foreseen way to stuff data from one `std::istream` source into another `std::ostream` sink, like `std::ofstream` is to just use the `<<operator` with sources `std::streambuf` argument, like

`sink << source.rdbuf();`

### Background

I'm designing a C++ converter module, that takes custom data (i.e. measurement data), in this example out of a database *mddb* via the C++ library *odb*, converts it into another format, called *df* here, and now comes the important part: Makes that converted data available for at least an `std::istream` and also an `std::fstream`. This is because, the `std::istream` can be used for a HTTP download via *Wt*s `Wt::WStreamRessource` interface and the file stream obviously, to just store the data as a file.

[image: class diagram]

Comment: Is the data, that you want to transfer from `????` to your `ostream` formatted or unformatted?

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply the C++ concepts of formatted input here, but it's data which white spaces should be preserved.

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question... Do you want to design an object that gives line-by-line data and under the hood extracts and converts stuff from a db?

Comment: Still your question is unclear! You seem to want to construct a resource (istream-like) and at the same time do something with output (fstream/file)?

Comment: First: It doesen't has to be just one class, I could imagine adapter classes to an intern conversion class.

This module/classes should take data from a db, convert it, and then make this data usable to be saved as a local file (so stuff it into an `std::ofstream`) and also to be saved remote. Saved remote means for example, as an HTTP download, a library called Wt does this via the `WRessourceClass` that wants to access the data via an `std::istream` to deliver it nicely via http/tcp.

Comment: Could you please provide a better description of exactly what types you expect this stream to operate on? Do you need to take complex DB objects, convert to strings, and make available via a stream extractor, for example?

Comment: It's exactly like you say @Snowman , I convert this DB objects to strings, and want to store them as a file and also send it via http to remote locations. The mentioned `Wt` framework offers this, with the solution that one can give the framework an `std::istream` to the source, so it can access it for async sending via http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a `std::basic_streambuf` is basically the building block of a `std::XYZstream`. Using one or the other is not choosing between two implementations, it is a choice between a basic building block and a more advanced stream interface that people expect. Use a stream.

Based on your comments, it appears that you may be getting hung up on the idea of *buffering*.

Try to think of this as something similar to reading lines from a file, except you are reading records from a database. Instead of reading a file line by line, you are pulling data from a table record by record:

```
idbstream in(<DB connection info here>);
ostream out(...);
while (in) {
  db_record r;
  in >> r;
  out << r;
}
```

In your extraction `idbstream::operator>>(db_record&)` you handle your query logic, buffering enough input to be able to construct a DB record object, whatever you need. You only return once you have a full DB record and have updated that object. You could also forgo the syntactic sugar of `operator>>` entirely and do a move construction and return inside your stream:

```
db_record idbstream::readRecord() { ... }

out << in.readRecord();
```

For efficiency, db_record should have a move constructor and it should be created at the same time it is returned.

Finally, the details of *how* the DB stream performs the conversion are deliberately left unsaid. You could use an adapter, or some more complex logic to select the type of object and convert multiple record types.

Also note that the output stream is just that, an output stream. I make no assumptions about what is on the other end of that stream. As you allude to in your comments it could be a file, standard out, an HTTP connection, whatever you need. The DB record class itself would handle its serialization in an implementation-agnostic manner (the only thing that really matters is binary v. text).